# How to configure locales to Unicode in a Docker Ubuntu 14.04 container?

Tags: 14.04, locale, unicode, docker

I installed a Ubuntu Trusty container using Docker, and when I connect to it, I can see that the locale is set to the bare minimum:

```
sudo docker run -i -t <id> /bin/bash
root@<id>:/# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I need to use an **Unicode** locale (for instance the US English one, `en_US.UTF-8`).

I tried to edit the /etc/default/locale file and put this inside:

```
# cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

But even after leaving the container and coming back, the locale is still not properly set.

I also tried using the `update-locale` command, without any success:

```
root@cab13a6abe4f:/# update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
root@cab13a6abe4f:/# locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

On my local configuration, I have the following configuration:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

How can I have the same in my Docker container?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `/etc/default/locale` file is loaded by PAM; see `/etc/pam.d/login` for example. However, PAM is not invoked when running a command in a Docker container. To configure the locale, simply set the relevant environment variable in your Dockerfile. Example:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the explanation about PAM as well. In the end, I just need to re-build the image (using `sudo docker build .`) and it works fine.

Answer (score 57):

I use this in my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Set the locale
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

One can also use the `ENV` one-liner:

```
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `locale -a` shows that the locale has been removed from the base image entirely. `locale-gen` generates it again and makes it available.

Comment: Where is this `dockerfile`? Can it be edited for downloaded image?

Comment: @MikhailBatcer you can create a `Dockerfile` in your project directory and use the `FROM` directive to extend an existing image. Then just append the mentioned lines. Find more about the `Dockerfile` [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Comment: I got the following error: `locale-gen: not found`. Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39761477/1743367

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

If you get the `unsupported locale setting` error and don't want to install any new locales.

Comment: You can also avoid rebuilding the image for a single run:

`docker-compose run --rm -e TERM=xterm -e LANG=C.UTF-8 worker bash`

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it helped me
in `Dockerfile` after my image I add

```
ENV LANG='en_GB.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_GB:en' LC_ALL='en_GB.UTF-8'
RUN echo en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
```

and run

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://daten-und-bass.io/blog/fixing-missing-locale-setting-in-ubuntu-docker-image/) extended solution solved my issue with python locale in Ubuntu docker container:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales \
    && sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales \
    && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8 
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```